# Equality on type which is not inductive type

Tags: coq

I want to think about equality on real number in Coq.

But `R` in `Coq.Reals.Reals.` is not inductive type, so I can't define functions like `Nat.eqb`.

How do I define equality on real numbers in Coq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real numbers are axiomatized in Coq, and so is their equality operator:

```
Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.

Check Req_EM_T.

(* forall r1 r2 : R, {r1 = r2} + {r1 <> r2} *)
```

The `{r1 = r2} + {r1 <> r2}` type is an informative boolean that gives you a proof of whether the two real numbers are equal.